# Login with google openid and return on particular url i want add more data so give form action to the same return url

Tags: php, forms, google-openid

when login with Google openid then comes on returning url then if we add some data in database for move to another form page to give form action on that page to the same homepage in php.

Login with google openid and to particular url and then list of large is showing and i want ot add more data and show into my data list and after add i want to remail on that same url which is generated by login with google openid.

Comment: when login with googleid and i return on a particular page i have list of data which is generated by database table.and i want to add more data and i click on the add button in the list and go to the page address and fill form fields and press submit button i want to submit form and give action to that page where the retrieved data list or rows are showing with a message.

Comment: if someone have the perfect solutions then quickly understand the issue and give response early.